# Whats the cooldown timer on Blue/Red buffs, Dragon, and Baron?

Tags: league-of-legends

Just curious what the re-spawn timers are.

Answer (score 7):

Both Red and Blue buffs (Lizards/Golems) spawn at 1:55 and respawn 5 minutes after EVERY creature in their camp is killed.

Dragon spawns at 2:30 and respawns 6 minutes after dying.

Baron spawns at 15:00 and respawns 7 minutes after dying.

Wraiths spawn at 1:55 and respawn 50 seconds after dying.

Wolves spawn at 2:05 and respawn 50 seconds after dying.

Minor golems spawn at 2:05 and respawn 50 seconds after dying.

Answer (score 5):

Red/Blue : 5 minutes

Dragon : 6 minutes

Baron : 7 minutes